# How to update existing value on realm database swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm, swift5

I want to make any row from 'false' to 'true' or vice versa depending on table view did select and did deselect method. That mean's I need to update the existing value. How to do that. My code is not working it's creating another row instead of updating the existing one.

Here is the table

[image: .]

Here is the model

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class TodoData: Object {

    @objc dynamic var todos: String = String()
    @objc dynamic var times: String = String()
    @objc dynamic var rows: Bool = Bool()

}
```

Here is the code I wrote for updating the value of the existing row:

```
    let data = TodoData()

            do {
                try realm.write {
                    data.rows = true
                    realm.add(data)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you literaly want to:

> I want to make any row from 'false' to 'true' or vice versa

Here's the code that will make all false rows true, and all true row false.

```
let toDoResults = realm.objects(TodoData.self)
for toDo in toDoResults {
    try! realm.write {
        toDo.rows = !toDo.rows
    }
}
```

I think though, you just want to toggle a row when the user makes a change in your tableView.

```
let selectedTodo = "a"
let results = realm.objects(TodoData.self).filter("todos == %@", selectedTodo)
if let thisTodo = results.first {
   try! realm.write {
      thisTodo.rows = !thisTodo.rows //will toggle from t to f and from f to t
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not updating existing data. It is creating a new `ToDoData` and inserting it.

You want to fetch an existing `ToDoData` and update in `write`. Here is an example.

```swift
let todos = "a"
guard let data = realm.objects(ToDoData.self).filter("todos == %@", todos).first else { return }
try! realm.write {
    data.rows = true
}
```